# wxPython global counter

Tags: wxpython

For a wxPython app I'm creating, I need for there to be a variable that counts the number of cycles that the program goes through.  I have multiple panels which are defined in their own class.  The frame class creates an instance of them all and the panels are shown or hidden depending on what buttons the user clicks.  For the bulk of the program, the "game" rotates through three panels (which I'll call p1, p2 and p3).  When you reach p3, the program takes you back to p1 *\if you have gone through the cycle under a certain amount of time.  Also, it keeps track of other data as the program is run.  My problem is that I'm not sure how to keep track of this data.  I've tried having class variables in my frame class which would presumable be accessible to all of the panels by using the GetParent() method but I have had limited luck with that approach.  I've also tried using global variables but this has also led to a dead end.  Any information on how I could possibly accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of no reason why global variables wouldn't work unless you are spawning subprocesses. To avoid having to declare the globals, put them in an object like a dict:

```
myglobals = {'count': 0}
class whatever:
 def blather():
  myglobals['count'] += 1
```

Comment: When I update one of the globals from one panel, it doesn't carryover to another panel.  In one of my panels, I say to update the count when the user pushes a button, and in another I want to access the current count.  When I do that, I only get the initial number the count was set to.  But in the panel where I do the incrementing, I am able to see what the count is at.  Any idea on why this might happen?  (hopefully I explained it correctly)

Comment: Yes, wxPython might be running each panel in a subprocess. Then you'll need to do some interprocess communication. Not sure offhand what would work best for that. Shared memory, maybe.

Comment: ahh I figured out the problem.  I'm using static text to represent what I want, and that means the text is ... static.  I'll just have to figure out some way to update the text every time I redisplay the panel.  Also, I was incorrectly implementing my global variables and I didn't know about the dict structure so thanks a lot for your help.  Much appreciated.